# Should Nix packages set `LC_ALL` themselves?

Tags: unicode, nix

At least on non-NixOS, it looks like Nix-installed packages do not use proper encoding. For example, https://github.com/srid/emanote/issues/125

They do not work, unless something like `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8` is manually set. What is the Nix way to obviate users from having to do this manual configuration?